# Create new column based on mean of values that are found in specific rows in R

Tags: r, rna-seq

I have table like this and would like to count genes that appear the most (lets say top 10 genes) and then find out mean of tail_len for those top 10 genes.

|  | gene | tail_len |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SPAC20G4.06c | 3 |
| 2 | SPCC613.06 | 5 |
| 3 | SPAC6F6.03c | 2 |
| 4 | SPAC20G4.06c | 3 |
| 5 | SPBC23G7.15c | 5 |
| 6 | SPAC589.10c | 2 |
| 7 | SPBC23G7.15c | 3 |
| 8 | SPAC22H12.04c | 1 |
| 9 | SPAC22H12.04c | 12 |
| 10 | SPAC6G10.11c | 8 |
| 11 | SPAC589.10c | 31 |
| 12 | SPBC18E5.06 | 16 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way with `slice_max`. I have defined two variables, `ties_ok` and `max_n`. The latter is set to 3 to test the code, you want `max_n <- 110`, the former can bee set to `FALSE` if you want to discard ties and keep only the first rows found.

```r
df1 <- "    gene    tail_len
1   SPAC20G4.06c    3
2   SPCC613.06  5
3   SPAC6F6.03c     2
4   SPAC20G4.06c    3
5   SPBC23G7.15c    5
6   SPAC589.10c     2
7   SPBC23G7.15c    3
8   SPAC22H12.04c   1
9   SPAC22H12.04c   12
10  SPAC6G10.11c    8
11  SPAC589.10c     31
12  SPBC18E5.06     16"
df1 <- read.table(text = df1, header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

ties_ok <- TRUE
#ties_ok <- FALSE
max_n <- 3L
df1 %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), mean_tail_len = mean(tail_len)) %>%
  slice_max(count, n = max_n, with_ties = ties_ok) %>%
  select(-count)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   gene          mean_tail_len
#>   <chr>                 <dbl>
#> 1 SPAC20G4.06c            3  
#> 2 SPAC22H12.04c           6.5
#> 3 SPAC589.10c            16.5
#> 4 SPBC23G7.15c            4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to test without a larger dataset. But this would be an approach using `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

foo <- tibble(
  gene = c("SPAC20G4.06c", "SPCC613.06", "SPAC20G4.06c", "SPAC6F6.03c", "SPBC23G7.15c"), 
  tail_len = c(3, 5, 1, 6, 7)
)

foo_top10 <- foo %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  slice_max(count, n = 10)

foo %>% 
  filter(gene %in% foo_top10$gene) %>%
  group_by(gene) %>%
  summarize(tail_len_mean = mean(tail_len))
```

Comment: The original dataset has over 7 million rows lol. I managed to solve this at the end with aggregate.